# Añadir filas a un dataframe que son copias de otras ya existentes

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Tengo un dataframe como el siguiente:

```
df = 
    id_ejemplo otra_columna columna_nan
0    15          'Hola'       nan
1    20          'Adios'      nan
2    8           'Bye'        nan
```

Y me gustaría añadir filas repetidas para rellenar la columna_nan según el siguiente diccionario (ejemplo):

```
dict = {15: [1,2,3], 20: [315], 8: ['Prueba_1', 'Prueba_2']}
```

De forma que el resultado final fuese:

```
df = 
    id_ejemplo otra_columna columna_nan
0    15          'Hola'       1
1    15          'Hola'       2
2    15          'Hola'       3
3    20          'Adios'      315
4    8           'Bye'        'Prueba_1'
5    8           'Bye'        'Prueba_2'
```

Actualmente estoy iterando por cada fila de df, calculando cuantas filas tiene que tener df al final con el mismo id_ejemplo, borrando la fila y añadiendo, iterando también, cada fila nueva según el diccionario.

Me gustaría saber si hay una forma más óptima de hacer esta operación, porque me da la impresión de que lo estoy haciendo de la pero forma posible.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente. Es bastante retorcido, pero seguramente más eficiente que iterar por filas.

Voy a desarrollarlo paso a paso para que se entienda, y al final lo resumo todo en unas pocas líneas.

Comienzo recrendo tu dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

# Crear dataframe de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(id_ejemplo=[15,20,8],
                      otra_columna=["Hola", "Adios", "Bye"],
                      columna_nan=[np.nan]*3))
# Reordenar columnas
df = df[["id_ejemplo", "otra_columna", "columna_nan"]]
```

[image: df]

y tu diccionario con datos adicionales (mala idea llamarle `dict`, lo renombro como `dicc`):

```
dicc = {15: [1,2,3], 20: [315], 8: ['Prueba_1', 'Prueba_2']}
```

Convierto este diccionario en otro dataframe:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=list(dicc.values()), index=list(dicc.keys()))
```

[image: df2]

Como ves, he usado como índice los "id". Tiene tantas columnas como elementos tiene la entrada más larga del diccionario (que corresponde al id 15). Hay `NaN` de relleno en varios sitios, insertados automáticamente por pandas.

Si ahora le hago una operación `stack()`, las columnas se convierten en índices de nivel 2, quedando algo más similar a lo que necesitamos:

```
df2 = df2.stack()
```

El resultado es una "Series" con los valores del diccionario original, indexado con un índice de dos niveles. El primer nivel es el id y el segundo un mero contador de casos dentro de ese id:

```
15  0           1
    1           2
    2           3
20  0         315
8   0    Prueba_1
    1    Prueba_2
dtype: object
```

Si ahora deshago el índice multi-nivel con `reset_index()`, los niveles se convierten en columnas, logrando así que cuando un índice de primer nivel (id) tenía varios casos, aparezca repetido.

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
```

[image: df2]

Ya estamos bastante cerca de lo que queremos. Nos sobra la columna `level_1`, y la `level_0` la rebautizaremos como `id_ejemplo`. La columna llamada `0` la llamaré `datos` de momento.

```
df2 = df2.drop("level_1", axis=1)
df2.columns = ["id_ejemplo", "datos"]
```

[image: df2]

Ahora podemos mezclar el primer dataframe con este último. La mezcla la hará en base a la columna `id_ejemplo`, ya que es la que tienen en común. Automáticamente repetirá las filas cuando `id_ejemplo` aparezca repetido en uno de los dataframes a mezclar.

```
mezcla = pd.merge(df, df2)
```

[image: mezcla]

Y ya sólo falta copiar la columna `datos` en `columna_nan` y eliminar la columna datos

```
mezcla.columna_nan = mezcla.datos
mezcla = mezcla.drop("datos", axis=1)
```

[image: Resultado]

### Abreviando

Dado el dataframe `df` y el diccionario `dicc`:

```
df2 = (pd.DataFrame(data=list(dicc.values()), index=list(dicc.keys()))
       .stack().reset_index().drop("level_1", axis=1))
df2.columns = ["id_ejemplo", "datos"]
mezcla = pd.merge(df, df2)
mezcla.columna_nan = mezcla.datos
mezcla = mezcla.drop("datos", axis=1)
```

Comment: Pues es enrevesado sí, pero funciona perfectamente y aligera muchísimo el tiempo de ejecución, conque perfecto. Muchísimas gracias!